# Using SQL (for MySQL), how can I UPDATE data on a row based on data from a previous row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these product SKUs in column `scott` that are alphanumeric (should always contain a number but not always a letter). The `id` column is auto-incremented. All of the data was imported line-by-line from a CSV file, so I know the order of the data is correct.

As you can see from this picture, some `scott` fields are just letters, which should have the previous number in front of them. For example, on `id` 5149, I'd like the `scott` to be 3780a.

[image]

**So the question is this:** Using SQL, how can I parse through the rows in order, prepending the `scott` number from the most recent field that contained a number, onto fields following it that don't contain a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using a user-defined variable to determine the most recent previous numeric value.

```
update yourtable y
join (
  select id, scott, @prevNumericId:=
          if(scott REGEXP '^[0-9]+$', scott, @prevNumericId) prevNumericId
  from yourtable, (select @prevNumericId:=0) t
  order by id   
  ) t on y.id = t.id and y.scott = t.scott
set y.scott = concat(t.prevNumericId,y.scott)
where y.scott not REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46d47/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
update t
set scott = CONCAT(
           (select scott
            from tablename
            where id = t.id - 1),
            scott)
from tablename t
where Scott not like '%0%'
and Scott not like '%1%'
and Scott not like '%2%'
and Scott not like '%3%'
and Scott not like '%4%'
and Scott not like '%5%'
and Scott not like '%6%'
and Scott not like '%7%'
and Scott not like '%8%'
and Scott not like '%9%'
```

Answer (score 0):

That good old first-(or in this case, last)-child problem, but this time on the same table..

This should do the job quite elegantly for you:

```
UPDATE mytable dest
JOIN (
SELECT mt.id, CONCAT(lnk.scott, mt.scott) AS newValue
FROM mytable mt

LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable lnk ON lnk.id < mt.id AND CONCAT('',SUBSTRING(lnk.scott, 1, 1) * 1) != 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable lnk2 ON lnk2.id < mt.id AND CONCAT('',SUBSTRING(lnk2.scott, 1, 1) * 1) != 0
    AND lnk.id < lnk2.id

WHERE lnk2.id IS NULL
AND CONCAT('',SUBSTRING(mt.scott, 1, 1) * 1) = 0
) AS source on source.id = dest.id

SET dest.scott = source.newValue
```

===

I don't have enough rep to comment but @sgeddes's solution is basically the same but using the user defined variable. That should be fine so long as the variable doesn't cross over between concurrent executions :)

This version will happily run concurrently, regardless.